# How do I calculate the effect size for a Spearman's correlation? Is it the same as for Pearson's correlation?

Tags: effect-size, spearman-rho

I'm having trouble understanding how can I calculate the effect size for a Spearman's correlation. I have the following results: rho= .352, df= 83, p<.01. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spearman is not the same as Pearson's correlation. In short: pearson is a correlation of a linear relationship whereby Spearman is a correlation for a monotonic relationship.

Note that effect size is a general term and can have different forms. Effect size is a quantitative measure of strength of a phenomenon (in your case the strength of a relationship). In this case, the correlation (rho) is itself a measure of effect size. 1 would be perfect (positive, and -1 a negative relationship) relationship and 0 would be no relationship at all.